# writing springer book in lyx

Tags: lyx

I followed the instructions given at http://wiki.lyx.org/Examples/Springer to install classes to write a Springer book. I am writing a single-author book. The installation has worked fine.

Now how do I exactly write a book in the Springer template in LyX?

There doesn't seem to be any other tutorial for that (or even a simple step-by-step instruction)

How to I make Lyx use `svmono`? Do I write each chapter one-by-one? Do I write a combined chapter?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Read the bottom of the site which you linked:

> LyX includes the template files svjour3.lyx for the sbvjour3 class,
>   svmono_book-master.lyx for the svmono class and
>   svmult_editor-master.lyx for the svmult class. (The files
>   svmult_author.lyx and svmult_appendix.lyx are subdocuments of
>   svmult_editor-master.lyx.)

So start Lyx, menu file, new from template, choose the appropriate template, write the first words, save it and you started.

Lyx is really good for beginning to use LaTeX.

Answer (score 2):

I ran into the same problem.  My solution:

1. Open a new document in LyX: File - New
2. Go to Document and then Settings.
3. In the window that pops go to Document Class and select Springer SV Mult

You are done and now you can start writing your book...

Took me a while but I am getting there...

Comment: OK... Let me amplify further here what I just found:  You can see document classes and some of them will be grayed out.  Just choose it and LyX will let you know what´s missing.  install whatever is missing from MiKTeX and refresh everything...